# How to vacuum sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, vacuum

I want to know how to vacuum sqlite database.
I tried  a syntax MANUAL VACUUM command for the whole database from command prompt:

```
 $sqlite3 database_name "VACUUM;";
```

But it's giving error as:

```
near "database_name": syntax error.
```

and also AUTO VACUUM:

```
PRAGMA auto_vacuum = INCREMENTAL;
```

And tried it for a particular table as:

```
VACUUM table_name;
```

But no result.

Answer (score 37):

You don't to specify the table name in the syntax. Only `VACUUM` works.

Also, it will clean the main database only and not any attached database files.

For more info, refer to the SQLite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).

Comment: this page suggests that its possible on the table http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_vacuum.htm

Comment: `VACUUM` from sqlite3 command line will only VACUUM main database. Attached databases can be VACUUMED only from sqlite3 verison `version 3.15.0`.

For older versions, database name *must* be specified, this works from `bash` as mentioned in @yöliitäjä answer: 
`$sqlite3 database_name 'VACUUM;'`

Comment: @VihaanVerma: It seems vacuuming tables not supported (on my SQLite v3.35.5 at least). When I run `VACUUM MyTable` it fails with message `Execution finished with errors. Result: unknown database MyTable`.

Answer (score 31):

Give the command like this:

```
$sqlite3 database_name 'VACUUM;'
```

As a matter of fact, this is the way to do also other queries from command line:

```
$sqlite3 database_name 'select * from tablename;'
```

You can use the full path to the db:

```
$sqlite3 /path/to/db/foo.db 'VACUUM;'
```

Answer (score 19):

Run the command:

```
VACUUM;
```

if you use DB Browser for Sqlite or

open Sqlite from command prompt:

```
cd C:\your_folder
C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\sqlite3.exe  -line your_db_name.db
```

and run

```
VACUUM;
```

Answer (score 0):

With [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) it is trivial. Open your database file with *DB Browser for SQLite* and execute the `VACUUM` command in the *Execute SQL* tab (Either press F5 or click the Execute button):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Do double-click on the database file, it will run directly in the command line. Then just type `VACUUM;`